# Implementing MQTT in PIC Microcontroller

Tags: tcp, pic, at-command, mqtt, gprs

I am trying to implement MQTT protocol in pic microcontroller using sim 900 gprs modem, already i have read the mqtt documentation version 3.1. Successfully i can able to make connection from gprs modem to myserver ip(117.218.81.15) using the following commands ...

1. AT
2. AT+CPIN?
3. AT+CREG?
4. AT+CGATT?
5. AT+CIPSHUT
6. AT+CIPSTATUS
7. AT+CIPMUX=0
8. AT+CSTT=\"INTERNET\",\"\",\"\"
9. AT+CIICR
10. AT+CIFSR
11. AT+CIPSTART= \"TCP\" , \"117.218.81.15\", \"1883\"

    As per documentation of MQtt protocol i have written connect packet function .
    After establishing a tcp connection i tried to send the connect_packet() function i am not getting any acknowledgement from broker.. Please help me for fixing this issue 
    I have checked with wireshark network analyser tool my data is arriving at 1883 tcp port ,but i don't why i am not getting any acknowlwdgement? The connect_packet code is
        `unsigned char topiclen = 0,time_out1=0,time_out2=0;
        unsigned char  connectdatalen,packetlen;
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        time_out1 = (time_out >>8) & 0XFF;
        time_out2 = (time_out & 0XFF);
        topiclen = strlen(sacketid);
        connectdatalen = 2 + 6 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + topiclen;

        packetlen = 2 + connectdatalen;

        buffer[0]  =  0X10;
        buffer[1]  =  connectdatalen;
        buffer[2]  =  0x00;
        buffer[3]  =  0X06;
        buffer[4]  =  'M';
        buffer[5]  =  'Q';
        buffer[6]  =  'I';
        buffer[7]  =  's';
        buffer[8]  =  'd';
        buffer[9]  =  'p';
        buffer[10] =  0x03;
        buffer[11] =  0x02;
        buffer[12] =  time_out1;
        buffer[13] =  time_out2;
        buffer[14] =  (topiclen >> 8);
        buffer[15] =  topiclen & 0XFF;
        for(i=0;i<packetlen;i++)
        {
            buffer[(i+16)] = sacketid[i];
        }
        uart_puts(buffer);
        uart_puts("\x1A");`
    In void main function the code is
    `uart_init(9600,16);
    DelayMs(100);
    gprs_init();
    gprs_tcpconnect();
    DelayMs(200);
    connect_packet("MQTT",180);
    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));`

Comment: Which broker are you using? have you tried turning on verbose logging on the broker?

Comment: Mosquito broker.... ya i have turned on verbose logging @ hardillb

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have already found solution because its an old post.

You should check the Protocol Name "MQIsdp" I think it must be "MQTT" if you are following MQTT-3.1.1 specification. MQTT spec says

> Blockquote The Protocol Name is a UTF-8 encoded string that represents the protocol name “MQTT”, capitalized as shown. The string, its offset and length will not be changed by future versions of the MQTT specification.

If your protocol name does not match with specification the broker will discard your packet silently. 
Also you will have to update your buffer array as MQTT takes 2+4 bytes in variable header of MQTT protocol.

Thanks